# Activiti and Vert.x Integration

Tags: activiti, vert.x

We are planning to use Vert.x for building our Micro-service Framework in our product, while at the same time we want to run Activiti as an embedded application in one of these micro-services. Note that I am new to both Activiti and Vert.x, so pardon me if I am blunt here, but since Vert.x is a reactive event-driven application framework and different than other common frameworks like Spring-boot, need to understand if Activiti running as an embedded application inside a reactive Vert.x framework has been tried before and it worked out perfectly fine without any issues. It would be great if there are any sample implementations to refer to for such an integration.

Comment: I think that's the same assumption you would have to do when you work in a "reactive" environment and using non-reactive libraries and/or frameworks. In any case, not all of them have to be...at least not for all scenarios.

Comment: I have worked both wit vertx and with activiti, but not combined. Vertx is managing threads for you, and this is where you may likely run into trouble, because activiti has a bunch of threading code itself. Anyway you need to avoid executing any long-running code on the event loop. For long-running task you use worker verticles, getting threads from a pool. This may be the way to initially integrate activiti. Good luck!

Comment: We are still evaluating the Workflow Management Framework to be used, if there is a possible risk with Activiti-Vert.x, would like to know if there are any other tried workflow management frameworks with well supported integration with Vert.x

Answer (score -1):

Did you manage to make progress on your implementation? Activiti 7 is moving forward to be more reactive and to make sure that integrates well in conjunction with reactive frameworks. I'm looking forward to hear your experiences around that subject.